# there are bug after call ajax function in hover function jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I update partial of html page by call ajax function 
Every 5 Minutes, there are some element object in  partial that by hover on open a popup windows.

my code run the first one works fine, but after a update Does not work properly and  per-hover opens two popup window.(hover function call twice)

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh2() { <? php
        echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url' = > CController::createUrl("browsingpap/UpdateAjax"),
            'update' = > '#type', )) ?>
    }
    window.setInterval("refresh2()", 300000);
</script>
<div id="type">
    <!-- update here after call ajax function--->
</div>
```

updateAjax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#goli").hover(function() {
            $('#popup5').bPopup();
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="popup5" style="display: none;"> <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
    <div class="content">popup window</div>
    <div id="goli">hover me for show a popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do all people use this syntax: `window.setInterval("refresh2()", 300000);`? It is awful. Use `window.setInterval(refresh2, 300000);`

Comment: read up on event delegation in the jquery documentation - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Share more details please. what that bPopup() function is doing? perhaps you replacing some element id somewhere?!? and whats the console error you get in second time hovering?

Comment: What does you AJAX change?

Comment: Why you have one extra `</span>`?

Comment: @alirezasafian is it important? it is for Design , it is corect

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I did what you said to me I was correct, but I still have problems

Comment: @maryam Please, provide a demo.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I  simplified my code, other data updated here

Comment: @alireza safian can u give your id ? my id is masoudy.maryam@gmail.com

Comment: @maryam You can google my name.

Comment: @alirezasafian Not reached yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95222/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-maryam).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this and see if it help:

```
$("#goli").unbind('hover').bind('hover',function() {
            $('#popup5').bPopup();
});
```

Anyway it will help us to see what is goig wrton if you will post the rest of your relevant code.